# Send array from HTML forn with predefines values

Tags: php, html, forms

Hello i try to send an array multiple times from html form and later access this value's but im  recieving undefined index. Can you please explain me what am i doing wrong here ?

First i take all values of checked checkboxe's

```
<label>
 <input type="checkbox" class="ck" name="event[]" id="event" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>"><span>Wybierz</span>
 </label>
```

Later on i process it and return values into hidden input fields

```
$event = $_POST['event'];
    foreach ($event as $key) {
        echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='event2[]' value='" . $key . "' />";

    }
```

And lastly i want to send this data together with some other input fields data to thankyou.php but im getting undefined index on my event2

```
if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
  if(count($_POST['name']) > 0) {
    $event2 =  $_POST['event2'];
      print_r($event2);

     }    
   exit;
      }
```

Till step 3 everything works perfectly fine .

Answer (score 0):

On each request, only the values that are in the current form are sent to the server. If you want to keep them through multiple requests, either you save them in the session or output them as hidden fields in your form.

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
$event = $_POST['event'];
```

to this line:

```
$event = $_POST['event[]'];
```

Let me know if that worked! :)